# Before May 1st, I could use the RestFB upload video, but now how I could upload video use by RestFB 2.8.0?

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

1, get authorizeURL

```
FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.LATEST);
        ScopeBuilder scope = new ScopeBuilder();
        scope.addPermission(FacebookPermissions.PUBLISH_ACTIONS);
        scope.addPermission(FacebookPermissions.USER_VIDEOS);
        authorizeURL = client.getLoginDialogUrl(appId, 
                redirectUri + "?partnerId=" + partnerId, 
                scope, Parameter.with("auth_type", "rerequest"));
```

2, from 1) get "code" then get the access token

```
com.restfb.FacebookClient.AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.LATEST).
                obtainUserAccessToken(appId, appSecret, redirectUri, code);
```

3, upload video

```
File videoFile = new File(filePath);
long filesizeInBytes = videoFile.length();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(videoFile);
FacebookClient facebook = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.LATEST);

ResumableUploadStartResponse returnValue = facebook.publish("me/videos",
                            ResumableUploadStartResponse.class, 
                            Parameter.with("upload_phase", "start"), 
                            Parameter.with("file_size", filesizeInBytes)); 

long startOffset = returnValue.getStartOffset();
long endOffset = returnValue.getEndOffset();
String vidId = returnValue.getVideoId();
int length = (int) (endOffset - startOffset);

String uploadSessionId = returnValue.getUploadSessionId();
while (length > 0) 
{
     byte fileBytes[] = new byte[length];
     in.read(fileBytes);

     ResumableUploadTransferResponse filePart = facebook.publish("me/videos",
          ResumableUploadTransferResponse.class,
          BinaryAttachment.with("video_file_chunk", fileBytes),
          Parameter.with("upload_phase", "transfer"),
          Parameter.with("start_offset", startOffset),
          Parameter.with("upload_session_id", uploadSessionId)
     );

    startOffset = filePart.getStartOffset();
    endOffset = filePart.getEndOffset();
    length = (int) (endOffset - startOffset);
}

GraphResponse finishResponse = facebook.publish("me/videos",
                GraphResponse.class,
                Parameter.with("upload_phase", "finish"), 
                Parameter.with("upload_session_id", uploadSessionId),
                Parameter.with("title", title),
                Parameter.with("description", "test upload video"),
                Parameter.with("privacy", "{\"value\":\"EVERYONE\"}"));
```

But now, get the access token failed and upload video failed.
How to use the RestFB 2.8.0 to upload the video to Facebook?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos#permissions

Comment: Without seeing the error, I think the problem is the publish_actions permission that is deprecated as @CBroe already mentioned.

Comment: Yes, publish_actions permission that is deprecated. But now how to upload video by restfb? which permisson need get?

Comment: Additional information: publish_video is a new permission to let a user stream live video to Facebook. Perhaps this is useful in this context